# Input trapping background iPhone app

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, smartphone

I want to create an iPhone app that will run in the background and can trap all user input. In certain scenarios it should also have the capability to make the iPhone reject the input just like we can do in Windows.

Please tell me whether this is possible, and if so how. If not what other smartphones may provide this capability.

Comment: I cannot speak for iOS. However, since you added the `android` tag... Fortunately, this is not possible on Android, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Thank God this is not possible, both for the security reasons mentioned, and because, as someone else said, an app in the background is on suspend mode...

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible on iPhone OS. As in iPhone, once your app goes in background it's in suspended mode. It can not execute anything. You can try on Android, as in Android you can create services which can run in background. But yes, on Android too, you can not trap all events, as security components of Android do not allow that.

Comment: i think he wants to capture all input on the device by the user not just in his application or whilst it's running...

Comment: but there are many spywares/parental control apps for iphone. i think somehow its possible

Answer (score 0):

I'll just say that iOs spyware is more about a social engineering and what you requested is not technically possible via official SDK.

To reject the activities, use a Restrictions given to you by Apple.

Convince the target users your feature replacement is better, safe, they want it - and they'll set-up the restrictions, replace the standard app with yours - profit.

PS
That's realists site, not a c00L-h@c|k3rs playground.